# Start Thread Group immidiately without any delay

Tags: jmeter

I have some Thread Groups with Startup delay. This delay is needed in the actual execution. But while validating the Thread Group before the actual run, I don't want to wait for that delay and wants to run that Thread group immediately.

How to override the StartDelay timings for Thread Group. So that I can directly execute that command without doing any changes for testing the Thread group.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Thread group's startup delay using property, for example

```
${__P(startupDelay , 1000}
```

This way delay will be 1000, unless you add startupDelay JMeter property which override (with 0 for example)

Answer (score 1):

Since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30/) there is `Validate` entry in the Thread Group context menu:

[image]

According to the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

> Validation Mode:
> This mode enables rapid validation of a Thread Group by running it with 1 thread, 1 iteration, no timers and no Startup delay set to 0. Behaviour can be modified with some properties by setting in user.properties:
>
> - `testplan_validation.nb_threads_per_thread_group` : Number of threads to use to validate a Thread Group, by default 1
> - `testplan_validation.ignore_timers` : Ignore timers when validating the thread group of plan, by default 1
> - `testplan_validation.number_iterations` : Number of iterations to use to validate a Thread Group
> - `testplan_validation.tpc_force_100_pct` : Whether to force Throughput Controller in percentage mode to run as if percentage was 100%. Defaults to false

So you can run your Thread Group using `Validate` menu entry and it will ignore any startup delay and if defaults are not suitable for you they can be overriden via [relevant JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#validation)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, Thanks for the response and this is very useful to validate the Thread groups rapidly. But we are also using Ultimate Thread groups (avail in plugin) which doesn't have Validate option :(. Is there any way to add Validate option in Ultimate Thread groups?